Invoice is still in the pending state even after the order is placed
I am facing an issue in the commerce module where the issue is happening for the prepaid and recurring as well where the invoice is not getting updated to the Paid state even after the order is completely paid and placed.
From the initial analysis, got to know the the balance is not set to zero even after the order is placed, so the isPaid is always sending false for the isPaid function.
commerce module version: 8.x-2.39
commece_invoice module version: 8.x-2.0-rc3

Bug reports need to be posted on drupal.org in the issue queue of the mentioned module to make the maintainers aware and fix the problem for everybody.

In drupal.org, it was mentioned that I have to post it here. so I posted it here. will post it in Drupal.org as well.. Thank you.

I don't see a bug here. This looks to me like a configuration issue, but there's not enough information here to diagnose it. Your best bet would be seeing if someone is available in the #commerce channel in Drupal Slack. Order placement happens irrespective of payment capture when checkout is completed.

Thanks for the response. Issue that I observed was that we have written a custom eventsubscriber on the onPaid event and that is not getting triggered when the order is placed. that is why I thought it maybe an issue in the commerce core. More precisely to say that the balance was not updated to zero when the oder was placed.
